# Apply additional TypoScript template to root page only

Tags: templates, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

I have a root page with two TypoScript templates in this order:

1. Root Template (the root template)
2. Additional Template (a non root template)

My problem is the second template is ignored. I just want that the second template applies to the root pages only. How would this be possible, without linking the root page to a subpage or using conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create templates records (let's say `main` and `subpages`) NOT in the root page but for an example in sys folder.

On main page create additional template, include `main` and at `Options` tab set `subpages` in `Template on next level` field.

[image]

Comment: and then the `main` template won't cascade to the next level?

Comment: @Urs I made only fast test, it didn't, but OP need to test carefuly himself

Comment: Ok, because I always thought this would cascade. Because of that, I usually set a "remove TS I've set for the home page only" script on next level, which is of course tedious. Ah, maybe the difference is that I store the main template IN the root page - and then it cascades!

Answer (score 1):

For the record - here's the condition that does this too (although OP said without conditions):

```
[treeLevel = 0]
[global]
```

Can be helpful sometimes, as there is no `hasPid` condition, only `pidInRootline`and `pidUpInRootline`